# Why the semicolon couldn't place in the CommandText of a OracleCommand when C#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

Why **the semicolon(';')** couldn't place in the **CommandText** of a OracleCommand when **C#**

Just like below:

```
string sql = "select * from table1;";
OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(sql , con);
oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
oc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The result would turn out to be a error.

Why? Can any one tell me the reason?

Comment: Apparently, Oracle (or the Oracle provider) will automatically add the semi-colon for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the comments, we've worked out the answer for you. Just so you get an official "answer", here it is from the OracleOverflow site (see below):

> An OracleCommmand can run only 1 sql or plsql statement at a time. There is no need of separating multiple statements.
>
> The semicolon is part of documentation to divide multiple statements. It is not part of the single DDL statement. For an OracleCommand there is no need to append a semicolon because it can only handle one statement at a time.

Edit: This was the original link, which is now dead: http://www.oracleoverflow.com/questions/145/running-ddl-through-an-oraclecommand-without-the-semicolon

Alternative: http://web.archive.org/web/20100806014022/http://www.oracleoverflow.com/questions/145/running-ddl-through-an-oraclecommand-without-the-semicolon

Question:

> When trying to run a series of DDL commands through an OracleCommand
>   object, I get an ORA-00911 'invalid character' error if I include the
>   final semicolon, even though this is part of the SQL syntax in the
>   documentation. It also means that you can only execute SQL one
>   statement at a time, rather than executing a whole SQL script at once,
>   which seems very odd to me.
>
> After googling for a bit, I found that a workaround is to wrap the DDL
>   in an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PL/SQL statement, but again it fails if the
>   DDL has a semicolon at the end (apart from PL/SQL create statements,
>   which require the semicolon).
>
> Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour? The semicolon is in
>   the syntax documentation, so I would have assumed it is always
>   required, but it fails if the semicolon is included...

Answer here:

> An OracleCommmand can run only 1 sql or plsql statement at a time.
>   There is no need of separating multiple statements.
>
> The semicolon is part of documentation to divide multiple statements.
>   It is not part of the single DDL statement. For an OracleCommand there
>   is no need to append a semicolon because it can only handle one
>   statement at a time.
>
> ADDED: You can bundle more than one statement into an BEGIN ... END;
>   Block (yes, this ends with semicolon). But this statements should be
>   DML, DDL or PL/SQL function calls. You cannot bundle multiple SELECT
>   statements into an BEGIN ... END; Block.

Comments:

Why OracleCommand has this limitation of only being able to run 1 statement at a time?

It's based on DbCommand specification in ADO.Net. It's not a limitation of OracleCommand only.

SqlCommand allows multiple statements in a single command, that must just be an 'addition' for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I finally finish it with calling sqlplus process. I try 'begin end' block at first but with select statement, and turn out failure. Thanks again to let me know that, it would be help from now on.

Comment: OracleOverflow not found

Comment: @Kiquenet: Too bad that site has disappeared without a trace. This is a great example of why it is good to include the content here on SO and not rely on links which may disappear.