# C# Parameterized Oracle Update fails on ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am attempting to dynamically update a set of database tables. I have two variables;
`table_name` & `field_name`. These are populated by a `foreach` loop, that loops through a `DataTable`. Everytime we hit a new row in the `DataTable` the names change respectively. Within this loop I create a new Oracle Connection and attempt to write an update with the current table_name/field_name. But Oracle keeps giving me an error on my `ExcecuteNonQuery` command. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: I have reformatted to include parameters, still does not work does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
foreach (DataRow fieldtable in setofTables.Tables[0].Rows)
{

    //do work                   
    table_name = fieldtable["table_name"].ToString().Trim();
    field_name = fieldtable["field_name"].ToString().Trim();

    MessageBox.Show(table_name + field_name);

    //create parameters

    OracleParameter fieldParamater = new OracleParameter("field_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    OracleParameter diffParameter = new OracleParameter("mark_diff_oracle", OracleDbType.BinaryFloat);
    OracleParameter wellIdParameter = new OracleParameter("id", OracleDbType.Char);
    //wellIdParameter.Size = 10;

    //create oracle connection and open 
    OracleConnection OrclCon2 = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + dbname + "; User Id=" + userid + ";Password=" + password1 + ";");
    OrclCon2.Open();

    //prepare sql to be passed to oracle 
    string UpdateOraSQL = "UPDATE " +table_name+ " set :field_name = :field_name - (:mark_diff_oracle) where  id = ':id' and :field_name is not null;";
    MessageBox.Show(UpdateOraSQL);   



    //create dommand
    OracleCommand UpdateDB = new OracleCommand(UpdateOraSQL, OrclCon2);
    UpdateDB.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //add parameters
    UpdateDB.Parameters.Clear();
    UpdateDB.Prepare();
    UpdateDB.Parameters.Add(fieldParamater).Value = field_name;
    UpdateDB.Parameters.Add(diffParameter).Value = mark_diff_oracle;
    UpdateDB.Parameters.Add(wellIdParameter).Value = id;
```

Comment: Your SQL *isn't* parameterized - you're trying to embed the values directly in the SQL. **Don't do that.** Use parameters instead.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ... use parameters instead - sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4915w86f.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem I ran into with parameters is incorporating my variable that holds the table name. In a parameter sql string can i break out of it and add + table_name +? I have read that table name cannot be added to the list of parameters. Thank you.

Comment: Can you really use parameters for column *names* as opposed to column *values*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the sql statement. Change the following code

```
string UpdateOraSQL = "UPDATE " +table_name+ " set :field_name = :field_name - (:mark_diff_oracle) where  id = ':id' and :field_name is not null;";
```

to

```
string UpdateOraSQL = "UPDATE " +table_name+ " set :field_name = :field_name - (:mark_diff_oracle) where  id = ':id' and :field_name is not null";
```

See the following link for more information

[why the semicolon couldn't place in the CommandText of a OracleCommand when C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212575/why-the-semicolon-couldnt-place-in-the-commandtext-of-a-oraclecommand-when-c-sh)

If the problem is still not resolved, it might be helpful if you post the entire exception message also.

Comment: This worked! I was able to run the original code which was a concatenation of variables and sql. Thanks alot to you for your help and for everyone that contributed I am in your debt!

Comment: This method has SQL injection problem.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you cannot use parameters to define the column that you're updating.
AFAIK, you can only use parameters for the values that you'd want to set.

So, you'll have to create the query using string concat:

```
string sql = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + fieldName + " = :p_Value  WHERE id = :p_Id";

OracleCommand UpdateDB = new OracleCommand(sql, OrclCon2);

UpdateDB.Parameters.Add ("p_Value", ... ).Value = "foo";
UpdateDB.Parameters.Add ("p_Id", ...).Value = 4;
```

Offcourse, you should make sure that the variables you're adding to the string do not contain any harmfull statements.  You should do sanity checks on them.
Perhaps, you can even verify if the tableName or the fieldName that has been passed, is a valid / existing tableName/columnname.

Comment: And also, one should check that the column name is valid for what is being done if it has come from user input.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, one does not say `COLUMN <> NULL`.  The proper syntax is `COLUMN IS NOT NULL`.