# Execute Oracle SQL query ending with semicolon

Tags: sql

How to execute a SQL query properly? 
When I want to execute a `select` statement I have to do it like this:

```
select id from test_table
```

instead of:

```
select id from test_table;
```

Why is the ";" not allowed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you include the exception you are getting and the c# code.

Comment: Where do you run this? In a SQL client like SQL Developer or SQL\*Plus you have to use the `;` to terminate a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this answare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6213159/2229993). It gives you the explanation you are looking for.